# what do i have to do to work with xml in vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

i am trying to use xmlreader and all of those, but i do not know how to reference or import them. i am beginner so please be gentle. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 then you should really look at XML Literals.  It allows you to work with XML directly in your code and has built-in query support.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx

Example

```
Dim x = <xml><p>hello</p><p>world</p></xml>
```